# Silver DDPG paper, what does the "dads" mean here?

Tags: probability, derivatives

[equation on page 2 of paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3AsT.png)

The above is on page 2 of the paper here:  http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/silver14.pdf

I cannot understand what the trailing dads means.  It has something to do with action "a" and state "s".

I'm looking here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation

But there are more than one that use "d" so I'm still confused.

Edit:  Yes, I would like to know what it means in this context.

Comment: Which d are you talking about? The $da$/$ds$? Like are you wondering what it means in general or what it means in this specific context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the integral

$$J(\pi_\theta) = \int_{\mathcal{S}}\rho^{\pi}(s)\int_{\mathcal{A}}\pi_\theta(s,a)r(s,a)\, da \, ds.$$

This is integral over the action space $\mathcal{A}$ and the state space $\mathcal{S}$. The $da\,ds$ is just a formal notation that the first inner integral is integrated with respect to the action $a$ and the outer integral is integrated with respect to the state $s$.

Imagine we had a derivative

$$\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}=g(x).$$

If we want to determine the function $f(x)$ we need to invert the differntiatiation this is done by using the integral. Hence, we write

$$df=g(x)dx \implies \int df = \int g(x)dx$$
$$f(x) = \int g(x) dx.$$

Comment: that is an awesome explanation of how all the tiny bits that have been differentiated are added up for the integral.

Comment: @flexitarian33 Glad that the answer was helpful to you.